# Set infinite timeout GET_LOCK() in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

GET_LOCK() in MySQL, accepts a negative value for timeout and is interpret as infinite timeout.

**MySQL Documentation:** [GET_LOCK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock)

> Tries to obtain a lock with a name given by the string str, using a timeout of timeout seconds. A negative timeout value means infinite timeout. The lock is exclusive. While held by one session, other sessions cannot obtain a lock of the same name.

But in MariaDB I can't find the way to replicate that infinite timeout, because there's nothing specified in the documentation.

**MariaDB Documentation:** [GET_LOCK()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/get_lock/)

> **GET_LOCK(str,timeout)** [...] 
>   str is case insensitive for GET_LOCK() and related functions. If str is an empty string or NULL, GET_LOCK() returns NULL and does nothing. timeout is rounded to the closest integer.

I could replicate GET_LOCK() with infinite timeout of MySQL in MariaDB?

Comment: Try a very high timeout.

Answer (score 3):

MariaDB does not accept negative values for `GET_LOCK`:

```
MariaDB [test]> do get_lock('test', -1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                             |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect timeout value: '-1' for function get_lock |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What you can do is use `0xffffffff` to emulate the same behavior in MariaDB:

```
MariaDB [test]> do get_lock('test', 0xffffff);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.85 sec)
```

Comment: Brilliant! where is the doc of this "trick"? its quite surprising that accepts an hexadecimal value. Thank you soo much

Comment: there is not need to document this. One can always emulate "infinite" with "extremely large".  2^32-1 seconds is 136 years, which is good enough for infinite. you can use larger values, second parameter is actually a double, so you can set lock to wait until the end of our galaxy.

Comment: @BigHelmet - To quell your 'surprise':  (1) The function accepts an expression.  (2) An expression can be simply a constant number.  (3) Hex is a way to represent a number.  (This logic applies in many places.)